# Find the velocity of the particle at t=a, t=2, t=3

Tags: calculus

$$s(t)=4t^2+6t+2$$

Find the velocity of the particle at $t=a$, $t=2$, $t=3$.

I did $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$, but I got for $s(a) = 12a^2$. However, my book is saying the answer is $12a^2+6$. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$$S=f(t)=4t^2+6t+2$$

$$\implies v=\frac{dS}{dt}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}h$$

$$v=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4(t+h)^2+6(t+h)+2-\{4t^2+6t+2\}}h$$

$$v=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{8th+4h^2+6h}h=8t+6\text{ as }h\to0,h\ne0$$

Can you find $v_{(\text{ at } t=a)}$?